# How can I design search field like zomato app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ui-design

I'm working on recreating a design similar to the corner radius used in the Zomato app. Despite my best efforts, I haven't been able to replicate the exact design. Below, I've included images for reference.

**Zomato's design**

[image]

I'm looking for guidance on achieving the same corner radius effect in my project. I've attempted several approaches, but none have matched the desired design.

**Mine design**

[image]

If anyone has experience or insights into replicating this specific design element, please share your knowledge. I would greatly appreciate any assistance, code examples, or suggestions to help me achieve this design.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you include your best effort ?

Comment: There is nothing much code. I just added TextFormField with border and border radius. Here I want to achive exact same corners like reference UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research,

I have found this [figma_squircle](https://pub.dev/packages/figma_squircle) package which helps to create exact same design which looks like zomato's view.

Designed view using [figma_squircle](https://pub.dev/packages/figma_squircle)

[image]

Sample code snippets:

```
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              height: 150,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: SmoothRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: SmoothBorderRadius(
                    cornerRadius: 15,
                    cornerSmoothing: 1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: ...
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 300,
                height: 30,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      offset: Offset(0, 4),
                      blurRadius: 4,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  cursorHeight: 10,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
                  controller: controllers,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      isCollapsed: true,
                      hintText: "Search your favourite food",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      suffixIcon: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          VerticalDivider(
                            indent: 2,
                            endIndent: 2,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.mic),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      isDense: true,
                      border:
                          OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the implementation i have written a sample code, make changes as per your requirement.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Search field example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 50,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                blurRadius: 2.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
              )
            ],
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search_sharp,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Search',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 1,
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.grey[350],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    // function for mic tap implementation
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.mic_none_outlined,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please compaire your attachment with I provided Zomato's search field. You will find the difference in border radius 

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the search bar in row and add a Container in the with minimum possible width (i.e: 1) and height as compared to the text of Container such that it leaves equal position both from top and bottom. incase the size of container is 50 take the height as 30

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).